# Java make application autorun when user logs on (Mac and Windows)

Tags: java, windows, macos

I am trying to get my java program to autorun when the user logs on. I have bundled the app so that on Windows its a .exe and on Mac its a .app.

What steps to i need to take in order to get my program to be able to autorun on both platforms?

Comment: For Windows you can either place it in the `startup` folder of the start menu of the user (which isn't as easy as it sounds) or create the executable to run as a service

Comment: This isn't a Java-specific question: You launch the program the same way you'd autostart any other program.

Comment: For windows, if you need to call it at particular time. You can also try Task Scheduler. You can have a simple batch file which will set the scheduler which will trigger your jar file.

Comment: On OS X, add a line in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` that invokes your program. Also, if it's a JAR file, the suffix should be `.jar`, not `.app` and certainly not `.exe`!

Comment: You can add a new registry entry in the Windows registry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run to specify a program which to run on startup. Or just add a new task to windows which is launched on startup.